# "Woods" and then verb. Singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

> The woods ushers forth its strength.

or

> The woods usher forth their strength.

?

Where "woods" is to be understood as a forest.

Comment: The forest ushers forth its strength. Answer for 'woods' may very well depend on which side of the Atlantic you are writing on.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Surely not? _A wood_ is an individual patch of woodland, _the woods_ are woodland as a type of land use. I know it is used in this sense in the US from the book title _Little house in the big woods_.

Comment: The character who says this is American, so I guess the original version "the woods ushers..." is correct. But... I'm noticing that the story also has European characters, and IIRC, they also refer to the forest as "woods." Curses. That doesn't sound easy to fix.

Comment: I thought I spotted a tree, but instead, I suppose I found a "woods." XD

Comment: @KateBunting: This particular instance of "woods" refers to an entire large forest.

Comment: @KateBunting I think woods is regionalized across the US, like "Bubbler" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_fountain I travel a lot, and you hear some of the strangest constructions. Little House in the Big Woods, as well as "On the Prairie" was written about Wisconsin, where we still use **bubblers**. It's a *huge* country linguistically. Sometimes the waitresses call me sweety, sometimes honey, and sometimes dear. I'm sure there are others. Valley speak is probably unintelligible in Rome NY. To matters worse, many of us still use Britishisms: "The Colour Out of Space"; obviously grey.

Comment: [Whose woods these are I think I know](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42891/stopping-by-woods-on-a-snowy-evening)  Robert Frost

Comment: Both sound somewhat overwrought; how can woods usher forth anything?

Comment: _This particular instance of "woods" refers to an entire large forest._ Yes, that is what I meant by 'woodland as a type of land use' - a large area covered in trees.

Comment: @Peter4075 Just ask the Na'vi.

Comment: @KateBunting I don't know why I ended up saying that, but my original intent was to point out that you were seemingly argumenting against WayfaringStranger's _multicultural_ statement using only a US-specific source.

Comment: I meant that, to me as a BrE speaker 'the woods'  implies a forested region , and the American Laura Ingalls Wilder seems to have used the word with a similar meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible say if it's singular or plural given *only* the sentence. It depends on how it's being used.

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. The sheep **is** grazing.
> 2. The sheep **are** grazing.

Because *sheep* is both singular and plural, the answer cannot be known unless you know how many sheep are actually involved in the activity.

---

In the same way, *woods* can be used to refer to both something singular and something plural.

Further, even if this is referring to a singular forest, some people might still think of it in the plural. It could be taken in the same way as *I went into the cool waters of the lake.* Similarly, some people do refer to a single forest as *the woods*.

I don't think that anybody would misunderstood either the singular or the plural. This seems almost equivalent to using a singular or plural verb with singular nouns like *choir*. Did *it* sing or did *they* sing? It's just a matter of perspective and interpretation.